# Using replace-regexp with lisp expression

Tags: regex, elisp

I have this line:

```
;Last updated: Sunday, January 23, 2011
```

I would like to replace the date with the current time. So, I used replace-regxp with the following key combinations:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET \(Last updated: \)[A-Z ,]*[0-9 ,]* RET \1\,(format-time-string "%A, %B %e, %Y")
```

But this yields the following result:

```
;Last updated: Tuesday, January 25, 2011unday, January 23, 2011
```

How can I get replace-regexp to replace the whole of the old date instead of just the first letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex only matches upper case letters. Since the `u` in `Sunday` is lower case, it only matches `Last updated: S`, so that's all that gets replaces.

To fix this add `a-z` to the character range.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for only capital letters.

Try this:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET \(Last updated: \)[a-zA-Z ,]*[0-9 ,]* RET \1\,(format-time-string "%A, %B %e, %Y")
```